# Error while importing sbt project in intellij due to temporary directory restrictions

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I just upgraded my version of sbt. Now I can't load sbt projects into intellij. The error I get indicates that something is trying to execute a file that has been stored under the /tmp directory. My system is configured to prevent anything from running under /tmp.

I've updated the my [intellij configuration](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties) and added the `-Djava.io.tmpdir=/path/to/different/directory` option to a directory I've used in the past to solve just this problem, but this hasn't helped.

I've tried setting the `JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.io.tmpdir=/path/to/different/directory"` environment variable and this hasn't helped either.

How do I set this option for sbt in the intellij context? I'm not having any trouble running sbt at the command line any more thanks to the environment variable.

intellij version: 2017.3.4

sbt version: 1.1.1

```
Error while importing sbt project:

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=384M; support was removed in 8.0
[error] java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/jna-94962664/jna6864913840915833425.tmp: /tmp/jna-94962664/jna6864913840915833425.tmp: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
[error]     at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
[error]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
[error]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
[error]     at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
...
[error] java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/jna-94962664/jna6864913840915833425.tmp: /tmp/jna-94962664/jna6864913840915833425.tmp: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently intellij now supports sbt natively, so I got rid of my old sbt plugin. Then I found that sbt has its own JVM settings under Build,Execution,Deployment->sbt->VM parameters. I added a `-Djava.io.tmpdir` and now it works fine.